# Rename a file using variables in the program - Python

Tags: python, variables, using, file-rename

I want to rename a file called decon.out using two variables in my program. So far I have

```
gwf = input ("Enter value: ")
myList = os.listdir('.')
    for myFile in myList:
        if re.match("^HHEMQZ", myFile):
            numE = myFile
        elif re.match("^HHNMQZ", myFile):
            numN = myFile
        else: 
            den = myFile
os.rename('decon.out', 'RF'+gwf+''+numE+'')
```

For example, `gwf = 2.5 and numE = HHEMQZ20010101`

I would then want decon.out to be renamed as `RF2.5HHEMQZ20010101` where RF will always be the same.
Currently when I run the script I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RunDeconv.py", line 77, in <module>
    os.rename('decon.out', 'RF'+gwf+''+numE+'')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you on Python 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead, `input()` interprets the input values as Python code turning your `2.5` input into a float number.

Answer (score 0):

About the error: in the string concatenation

```
'RF'+gwf+''+numE+''
```

all the members must be strings.

You can use

```
type(gwf)
type(numE)
```

to check which is a number.

You then just need to

```
str(gwf)
```

or

```
str(numE)
```

depending on which may be the case. Or probably both gwf and numE need the str() treatment, so your last line of code should look like this:

```
os.rename('decon.out', 'RF'+str(gwf)+''+str(numE)+'')
```